# Sbt submodule project doesn't recognize root variable

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to follow this [instruction](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/wiki/%5BSBT%5D-How-to-use-provided-libraries-in-run-configurations) to make IntelliJ play nice with `provided` and `compile` dependencies. However, I can't get the submodule to read its parent variable. Here's my root build.sbt

```
name := "vivace"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"
val hadoopVersion = "2.7.3"
val awsVersion = "1.11.155"


lazy val sparkAndDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,

  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % hadoopVersion,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % hadoopVersion
)

libraryDependencies ++= sparkAndDependencies.map(_ % "provided")

libraryDependencies += "com.cn" %% "sparrow-clf-parser" % "1.1-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % awsVersion
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % awsVersion
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % awsVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.github.seratch" %% "awscala" % "0.6.+"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0"
dependencyOverrides ++= Set("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.0")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "amazonaws", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "typesafe", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "overview.html" => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

And here's my submodule build.sbt `mainRunner/sbt.build`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

lazy val mainRunner = project.in(file("mainRunner")).dependsOn(RootProject(file("."))).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= sparkAndDependencies.map(_ % "compile")
)
```

Here's the error I got

Error:Error while importing SBT project:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ncharass/MyProjects/CN/vivace/mainRunner/project
/Users/ncharass/MyProjects/CN/vivace/mainRunner/build.sbt:4: error: not found: value sparkAndDependencies
libraryDependencies ++= sparkAndDependencies.map(_ % "compile")
^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Comment: Irrespective of the other issues of your build, you'll need to downgrade the AWS SDK version to 1.7.4 to get Hadoop 2.7.3 JARs to link against it. It's a very brittle library & you can't upgrade anything but minor point releases